# i am getting this error "No default engine was specified and no extension was provided." in node.js when trying to send data into database

Tags: node.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "mydatabase"
});
app.get('/',function(req,res)
{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/app.html'));
});

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'js'); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.get('/', function(req,res)
{
    res.render('index');
});//inserting data
app.post('/insert', function(req,res)
{
    pool.getConnection(function(error,conn)
    {
        var queryString = "insert into customers(firstName,lastName)values('"+req.body.fname+"','"+req.body.lname+"')";
        conn.query(queryString,function(error,results)
        {
            if(error)
            {
                throw error;
            }
            else 
            {
                res.send('Inserted Successfully!')
            }
        });
        conn.release();
    });
});//server starting
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    app.listen(2000);
    console.log("Running at Port 2000")
});
```

I am making a web page in which I want to insert data by the user so I have created this code in node.js to perform data tranfer but it is showing

> No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i got my mistake its in app.set('view engine', 'js');
it should be app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
but when i fixed it a new error has arrived and that is 
 Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "D:\nodejs/views"